# Make the 'How to Format' box sticky/persistent

Tags: feature-request, design, editor, formatting

I was just writing a question and could not remember how to quote something. I did remember there usually is a box on the right giving me hints for things like this. The box wasn't visible however, there was a 'Similar questions' box.

I had to go so far as to copy my question to some text editor and discard it in order to start a new question to finally see the 'How to Format' box and lookup to use '>' for quotes. I consider this a highly frustrating user experience.

So please make the 'How to Format' box permanently visible.

Comment: Click the "?" icon in the toolbar of the editor---the one on the far right-hand side.

Comment: Wow thanks. I didn't see that.